# Why document.body.scrollHeight can be greater than document.body.offsetHeight

Tags: javascript

I need help with this two elements properties.

According MDN [element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight) "this a height of the scroll view of an element; it includes the element padding but not its margin", and [element.offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) "Typically, an element's offsetHeight is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element vertical padding, the element horizontal scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element   CSS height."

I am trying to debug some javascript code and don't understand why document.body.scrollHeight can be greater than document.body.offsetHeight?
For example, my document.body.offsetHeight=909, but document.body.scrollHeight=1059 (body don't have any margins or paddings or borders), so we lost 150px somewhere. I inspected body and it height=909, and this is very confuse me. This reproduced in chrome and firefox.

Can you please help me in this question?

Comment: document.body != document.documentelement

Comment: Sorry guys, this is my terrible mistake, Friday evening :) I corrected my question.

Comment: Than...it's a good question ;)

Comment: Could we see a live demo that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I have some troubles with demo, because this issue reproduced in SharePoint :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offsetHeight property describes how far from the top of the current available space in the active window.  The scrollHeight property is how far in pixels from the inside top of a contain to the inside bottom, which is different than clientHeight on a container set to a limited height with overflow:scroll css property.

I am using most of these in project I am working on at http://prettydiff.com/jsgui/